# I am creating a DLL in C++ but it is giving me a persistant error

Tags: c++, dll

I am creating a DLL using the code provided to us by my instructor. However I have tried to compile it at home and it does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
template<class T>
class mySTLlist : public list<T> {
public:
    void addInMiddle(T t){}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,  mySTLlist<T>& lst) {
        for(mySTLlist<T>::iterator i = lst.begin(); i != lst.end(); i++)
            out << *i << ' ';
        out << '\n';
        return out;
};
```

It gives me an Error at:

```
mySTLlist<T>::iterator i = lst.begin();
```

It says that i need a `;` before it and it is not declared.
I am relatively new to C++

Comment: Unless you missed a chunk of the code at the very least you seem to be missing a closing curly brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good illustration of why it is important to include a *complete* example, and also to read all of the error messages.  Your code is missing some include headers; at minimum, it needs the following at the top:

```
#include<list>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

When I correct those and add the missing `}` at the end, and compile it, I get three errors:

```
foo.cpp:14:9: error: need 'typename' before 'mySTLlist<T>::iterator' because
'mySTLlist<T>' is a dependent scope
foo.cpp:14:32: error: expected ';' before 'i'
foo.cpp:14:49: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
```

The first one says that we need to add "typename" (note that this is in quotes, meaning the literal keyword `typename`, not the name of a type), so we add exactly what it says we need, changing that line to:

```
for(typename mySTLlist<T>::iterator i = lst.begin(); i != lst.end(); i++)
```

That fixes the problem.  The error that you are seeing is a follow-on error -- because the declaration of `i` was buggy, it skipped over it to see what it could do with the rest of the file.  The next time you use `i`, it complains that it hasn't been declared (which is, of course, because it skipped the declaration) -- and, likewise, the missing `;` error is because of how it's skipping past that first error.  So, fix the *first* problem, and that fixes the rest.

Comment: I assume your using gcc, as it gives you the nice error message, however it is quite possible that an informative error message is not shown depending on the compiler.

Comment: hey thanks, that solved the issue but then I get an unidentified reference error, but it does compile. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Jesse: A good point.  Sometimes it's helpful to run things through http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/ -- they make a big point of having thorough error checking in their compiler, and a webform to try it out online.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an iterator typedef:

```
typedef typename mySTLlist<T>::iterator myListIter;
```

and then write:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,  mySTLlist<T>& lst) {
    for(myListIter i = lst.begin(); i != lst.end(); i++)
        out << *i << ' ';
    out << '\n';
    return out;
```

Comment: Why does this need a `typedef`, rather than writing `typename mySTLlist<T>::iterator` directly in the declaration of `i`?

Comment: I does not need a `typedef`, it was just the first thing that came to my mind... :) I am not a native English speaker, so having a few minutes more I would write something very similar to your answer... One has to be quick in order to gain some Karma from C++ questions; there are so many C++ gurus on the SO, I am always late with my answers - as in this case :)

Comment: Fair enough.  I was hoping I'd missed something useful.  :)